# Nested states in angular how to access them

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to access a nested state. In my routes.js I have

```
.state('menu', {
url: '/side-menu-ineevent',
templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
abstract:true
})
.state('menu.settings.privacy_policy', {
  url: '/privacy_policy',
  views: {
    'settings': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/privacy_policy.html'
    }
  }
})
.state('menu.settings', {
  url: '/settings',
  views: {
    'side-menu-ineevent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
      controller: 'Settings'
    }
  }
})
```

I would like to access privacy_policy. I tried many path like

```
href="#/side-menu-ineevent/settings/privacy_policy"
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: did you try `"#/side-menu-ineevent/privacy_policy"`  or `"#/side-menu-ineevent/settings"` ?

Comment: why not using ui-sref?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write `abstract: true` in `menu.settings` state also, as it also has a nested state.

And then this url: `href="#/side-menu-ineevent/settings/privacy_policy"` should work.

Comment: as soon as I put abstract:true on menu.settings, the settings page is blank. It doens't work. I also tried to put  abstract:true inside the views but no luck.

Comment: don't just look at the screen. Check the inspector for errors. What error does it throw?

Comment: Also do you have ui-view in the settings.html file and in menu.html file?

Comment: using ionic but I just added <ui-view> </ui-view> on the html. same results.

Comment: No for ionic you use <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>, not ui-view, for ionic